# C# rdlc handling

Tags: c#, reporting, rdlc

In my application I'm hosting a Report viewer Control where I want to run different reports. To viewer and to application do not know anything about the reports and their datasets.

Is it possible to get all parameters (datasets, connectionstring, parameters) I need from the rdlc or rdl file like the report builder?

Best regards!

Comment: See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3e15701-c6fd-4c70-991f-5d58c4b4970e/get-parameters-and-datasets-from-rdlc-at-runtime?forum=vsreportcontrols

Comment: Thank you Peter. I have seen this snippet before but with it you only get the names of the datasets. In my case  I need the complete dataset object including Queries, Fields and so on.